# Location latitude and longitude not updated

Tags: java, android, button, gps, location

Code is here; https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java

Hello, I'm testing out this code, but at `startUpdatesButtonHandler()` and `stopUpdatesButtonHandler()` I get the message that these are never used. Where should I use these, have I forgotten something? I used the code linked above.

The lat lon are not being updated, is this because of the start and stop button not being used? I have to refresh the entire activity for it to be updated.

Comment: Check your layout file whether you have specified android:onClick="startUpdatesButtonHandler" and android:onClick="stopUpdatesButtonHandler" for the 2 buttons.

Comment: Yes thanks, Carnal already pointed out the onClick. I indeed forgot to set onClick in the xml..

Comment: I will add it to my answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Locate the UI widgets.
mStartUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_updates_button);
mStopUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_updates_button);
```

You need to set `onClickListener` on those two buttons.
Check the `main_activity.xml` file, it could be that `onClick` is already set there. However it says in the comments, and you can see it in the code that `startUpdatesButtonHandler(View view)` will do nothing if location changes is already been made.

Comment: Well.. That's embarrassing.. I forgot to set onClick in the xml... It works now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just adding the accepted comment as an answer. You need to add set them in your XML.

e.g.

```
     <Button
        ...
        android:onClick="startUpdatesButtonHandler"
        android:text="@string/start_update" />

    <Button
        ...
        android:onClick="stopUpdatesButtonHandler"
        android:text="@string/stop_update" />
```